# Org-journal won't recognize org-journal-dir?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Using the following `use-package` syntax, Org-journal doesn't recognize the org-journal-dir setting--instead, attempts to create a different directory with query `Journal directory ~/Documents/journal not found. Create one?`:

```
(use-package org-journal  
  :ensure t
  :custom
      (setq org-journal-dir "~/Dropbox/logs/journal/")
      (setq org-journal-file-format "%m.%d.%Y.org"))
```

I see no error messages--it just seems to ignore the directory setting. Is this a simple syntax error? I'm new to the package and to Org mode.

[Update]: Sometimes, I get the following error message on Emacs start:

```
Error (use-package): org-journal/:catch: Symbol’s value as variable is void: org-journal-dir
```

Comment: `(use-package org`  instead of `(use-package org-` (remove the final `-`) ?

Comment: Just realized there's a spelling error--it should read 'org-journal'. Corrected. It's org-journal in my .emacs file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for `:custom` is wrong.  See https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#customizing-variables.  It should be something like:

```
:custom
(org-journal-dir "~/Dropbox/logs/journal/")
(org-journal-file-format "%m.%d.%Y.org")
```

Either that, or use `:config` (or maybe `:init`, but probably not) with `setq`:

```
:config
(setq org-journal-dir "~/Dropbox/logs/journal/")
(setq org-journal-file-format "%m.%d.%Y.org")
```

Comment: Worked, thank you. I'm still fairly new to Emacs, just started using use-package, and it's clear my lack of elisp knowledge is an obstacle.